# How to find out font family used in plot title of ggplotly?

Tags: html, css, r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have created a plot using `ggplotly()` and really like the **font** used in it's `title`.

[image]

I have tried to figure out the font used in it by `inspect element` but nothing turns out to be same.

[image]

So I have `knit` the **document** & applied `inspect element` on it and could see these fonts and tried all one by one but nothing looks same: **"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;**

How can I replicate the font in my other charts or non plotly charts ?

Comment: search for the element id or class in the main css to check if it's using any font

Comment: This looks like a "serif" font.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman I am not sure how to do that but I have moved to below lines & have found few more fonts: `"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif;` under `.plotly div` so will try that

Comment: @stefan even I thought so and tried `plot.title = element_text(face = "plain", family = "Open Sans", size = 13)` but this is not the same.

Comment: Have you tried `family="serif"`?

Comment: thanks @stefan yes `family= "serif"` worked. I was trying "sans serif", "sans-serif", "Open serif" which were not working.